# options for local database in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, relational-database

I've written a Chrome Extension that does lookups in a flat data file via a binary search. The extension has grown in complexity and the lookup needs are getting more complex as well.

I'd prefer to use indexing and querying as I would in a relational database. Is there an option to use something like this in a chrome extension? I could get a lot of use out of only doing reading from the db, but writing (with indexing) would be great as well.

The extension is currently written in react/redux, so node modules are easy to add...

Comment: In Chrome you can still use WebSQL which is deprecated elsewhere. Or use the universal IndexedDB. There are libraries like PouchDB that can work atop of these two.

Comment: would this allow me to package a db file with the extension?

Comment: Only as a seed which you'll read on install and put into the real db.

Comment: oh, interesting!

Comment: At Chrome, it's safe to choose LokiJS for NoSQL based storage, and SQLite for relational database.